# Snowflake Append two tables together

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have data in a table and some new one in a s3 stage .
i want to append the stage data to the existing one .
what is the best way to do that in snowflake ?
Also it's in a script and i don't know what columns are in the tables but i know that they are identical , and none will match.

i tried to do some merge but i need to specify columns
i guess i can do a create table as (select both tables) but it makes me create a 3rd table...
Insert into , i don't have the columns name .

The result would be just the two tables together .
basically i want to apply a concat but to tables .

Thank you =)

Comment: How do you expect the end result to look? Please more concrete examples in the question

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: Please send us sample of the data , table structure . When you do a Create table AS (SELECT * from a table_A) , you don't need to specify a column name, it get the column name/data type from the columns in your select query.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT * from table_a
union
SELECT * from table_b
```